# Derive db.Model subclass from db.Key

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Given a db.Key instance, such as:

```
db_key = db.Key.from_path('ModelKind', 'UniqueKeyName')
```

Is there a way to return the class representation of 'ModelKind' as AppEngine is able to do internally?

Something like

```
db_key.class()
```

The end result is that I need to dynamically retrieve the class (to construct a new entity) given a key. I do not know the entity type ahead of time ('ModelKind' could be any model kind represented by our 'schema' classes (db.Model subclasses))

What I'd like to avoid:

```
import schema_module
cls = getattr(schema_module, 'ModelKind')
```

as it will limit 'ModelKind' to be defined in a specific schema_module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value "ModelKind" from the key instance via `db_key.kind()`. Then, you can use `db.class_for_kind()` to get the relevant class itself. So:

```
cls = db.class_for_kind(db_key.kind())
```

Comment: Just to add for those who come across this problem with ndb, the equivalent is `ndb.Model._kind_map[ndb_key.kind()]`

Comment: A further note - make sure that you've imported the modules with the classes you're looking to find. This is important news for larger projects. We've structured a parent module to import all ndb.Model subclasses, conveniently named `import models`. Hope this helps somebody!